# Using Twilio in Rails 4 - Uninitialized Constant Error

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio, uninitialized-constant

I am trying to integrate Twilio with my Rails 4 app. I followed a tutorial, but I keep getting an error. Right now I am getting an Uninitialized Constant Error. I provided the code below. Thanks in advance.

Routes.rb

```
get '/share_over_sms' => 'listing_collections#share_over_sms'
```

Listing Collection Model

```
require "messenger"

def clean_number
   client_number = self.client_number.scan(/\d+/).join
   client_number[0] == "1" ? client_number[0] = '' : client_number
   client_number unless client_number.length != 10
end
```

Messenger Module

```
module Messenger

   def send_sms(number)
      twilio_sid = "ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']"
      twilio_token = "ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']"

      @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_sid, twilio_token

      from = '+1xxxxxxxxxx'

      message =  @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
         :from => from,
         :to => "+1"+number,
         :body => "This is a test message."
      )
   end

end
```

Listing Collections Controller

```
def share_over_sms
   @client_phone = ClientPhone.new(listing_collection_params)
   @client_phone.send_sms(@client_phone.clean_number)
   redirect_to :back
end
```

[image: Error I'm Getting.]

Comment: Just post your complete error. Screen shot if possible

Comment: Added the error, @pradeepsapkota

Comment: check your routes for correct route and your controller for correct spelling. Sometime grammatical mistake gives pain.

Comment: Do you have a model for ClientPhone ?

Comment: I don't, client_phone is a column in the listing_collection table @FakhirShad

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong by using ClientPhone as class and then calling the 'new' method. The error is correct.

Comment: What to want to achieve there ?

Comment: A client_phone is associated with a listing_collection. Once the share button is pressed in the view, whatever data I enter there should be send to that client's phone. Does that make sense, @FakhirShad?

Comment: Is there any class for `ClientPhone` at all? Also, what tutorial were you following?

Comment: @philnash client_phone is a column in my table. I was using the Twilio tutorial.

Comment: We have a [number of tutorials available](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials). Which one were you using?

Comment: @philnash I was following this one. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html

Comment: Ok, can you share a bit more of your code? The relevant bits from your `ListingCollection` model, for example. Does your `Messenger` module get mixed into that model too?